# Difference between “him” and “his” in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the exact difference in meaning of following sentences:

> 1. I understand **his** quitting.
> 2. I understand **him** quitting.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, the action of quitting is the object of the sentence (the thing that you “understand”). This action belongs to “him” because of the possessive pronoun.

In the second sentence, “him” is the object of the sentence, and his quitting is something that you understand about him.